# How would the next slider work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Ok,
This is the code I'm using :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#rangePoints").change(function() { 
        var qty = $("#rangePoints").val(); 
        var price = $("#price").val();
        $("#qty").val(qty);
        $("#total").val(qty*price);
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
Price: <input id="price" type="text" value="10.50" readonly /><br/> 
Quantity: <input id="qty" type="text" value="1" readonly />
<input id="rangePoints" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1"/><br/><br/> 

Total Price: <input type="text" id="total" readonly />


Price: <input id="price" type="text" value="15.50" readonly /><br/> 
Quantity: <input id="qty" type="text" value="1" readonly />
<input id="rangePoints" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1"/><br/><br/> 

Total Price: <input type="text" id="total" readonly />
</body>
</html>
```

(Thanks to charles360 for helping with this javascript).

In the code above, only the first slider works (which has the price 10.50)...where as..the second one doesn't works.

I need to have multiple of these sliders and each slider has to perform the quantity * price function.
How would I make this happen ?

Thanks.

Comment: **http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got different elements that have the same `id`. `id`s should be unique on the page. It'll only look up the first `id` since they're supposed to be used only once.

If you want something that can be re-used multiple times on a page, use `class`es and `$(".className")` instead of `$("#idName")`